# Vue-CLI make sass file accessable globally

Tags: vue.js, sass

I've created a main.sass file in src/assets/scss/main.sass. There is only one var declared.

`$primary: #b2209d`

My Vue File:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="whatever">
      dawdaw
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass">
.whatever
  background: $primary
</style>
```

And my vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  css: {
    requireModuleExtension: false,
    loaderOptions: {
      css: {
        modules: {
          localIdentName: '[name]_[hash:base64:4]'
        }
      },
      sass: {
        prependData: `@import "@/assets/scss/main.sass";`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My vue/cli version is: 4.3.1.
When I'm importing my main.sass file directly in the vue file, it works, so I know that the path is def. right.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most infuriatingly dumb aspects of Webpack and Vue cuz you'd think they'd just make a simple handler for this in the config, but no. Every time Webpack changes, you have to learn all over again how to do this, and each time it gets progressively worse. Nuxt handles it much more simply and Vue should copy them. Last time I had to do it in a Vue PWA (before switching to Nuxt and never looking back), it went something like this:

```js
const globalSassFiles = ['~@/assets/styles/global.scss']

module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: globalSassFiles.map(src => '@import "' + src + '";').join('\n')
      }
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const types = ['vue-modules', 'vue', 'normal-modules', 'normal']
    types.forEach(match => {
      config.module
        .rule('sass')
        .oneOf(match)
        .use('sass-loader')
        .tap(opt => {
          return Object.assign(opt, {
            prependData: globalSassFiles.map(src => '@import "' + src + '"').join('\n')
          })
        })
    })
}
```

Preposterous, right?

Comment: holy cow. I will check it later and get back to you